# What's the proper way to access the filesystem from a bundle independent of the launcher?

Tags: osgi

I have a few resources (log files, database files, separate configuration files, etc.) that I would like to be able to access from my OSGi bundles.  Up until now, I've been using a relative file path to access them.  However, now my same bundles are running in different environments (plain old Felix and Glassfish).

Of course, the working directories are different and I would like to be able to use a method where the directory is known and deterministic.  From what I can tell, the working directory for Glassfish shouldn't be assumed and isn't spec'ed (glassfish3/glassfish/domains/domain1/config currently).

I could try to embed these files in the bundle themselves, but then they would not be easily accessible.  For instance, I want it to be easy to find the log files and not have to explode a cached bundle to access it. Also, I don't know that I can give my H2 JDBC driver a URL to something inside a bundle.

Comment: Can you clarify the question please. Strictly a bundle shouldn't always expect to have access to a filesystem at all... it might be deployed onto a device that doesn't have one.

Comment: Well, if you have the askers problems than those systems do not eally apply, do they?

Answer (score 2):

A good method is to store persistent files in a subdirectory of the current working directory (System.getProperty("user.dir") or of the users home directory (System.getProperty("user.home"))

Temporary and bundle specific files should be stored in the bundle's data area (BundleContext.getData()). Uninstalling the bundle will then automatically clean up. If different bundles need access to the same files, use a service to pass this information.

Last option is really long lived critically important files like major databases should be stored in /var or Window's equivalent. In those cases I would point out the location with Config Admin.

In general it is a good idea to deliver the files in a bundle and expand them to their proper place. This makes managing the system easier.

Comment: The database and config files would need to be readable independent of the current user (different users might start the app) and I'm guessing the current working directory can't be assumed to be the same each time the OSGi framework starts up?? I'm not really a Linux  expert to know where in /var I would put the data nor do I know what the Window's equivalent would be.  Is there some sort of generic Java method to get this directory?  I do like the idea of placing files in the bundle for initial deployment.

Comment: Files that need to be shared need a fixed place, like /var/myapp. However, delivering them as bundles and using config admin to control this location and content is usually a very good idea.

Answer (score 1):

You have some options here. The first is to use the Configuration Admin service to specify a configuration directory, so you can access files if you have to.

For log files I recommend Ops4J Pax Logging. It allows you to simply use a logging API like slf4j and Pax Logging does the log management. It can be configured using a log4j config.

I think you should install the DB as a bundle too. For example I use Derby a lot in smaller projects. Derby can simply be started as a bundle and then manages the database files itself. I'm not sure about h2 but I guess it could work similarly.